PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process in xtts_v2
I am trying to fine-tune a xtts v2 model but when i fit the trainer model i keep encountering the following error:

EPOCH: 0/1000
--> GPT_XTTS_v2.0-April-01-2024_12+01PM-0000000
Filtering invalid eval samples!!
Total eval samples after filtering: 0

 PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'd:/FineTuning TTS model/GPT_XTTS_v2.0-April-01-2024_12+01PM-0000000\\trainer_0_log.txt'

The Screenshot of the error is shown in the image.


Any Solutions??

go to
 c:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\trainer\generic_utils.py

and at the end of the close_open_files() function add this line
close_open_files('d:/FineTuning TTS model/GPT_XTTS_v2.0-April-01-2024_12+01PM-0000000\\trainer_0_log.txt')


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
